# iOS keyboard appearance messing up other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, ios-ui-automation

I have `UITextField`, `UIButton` and `UIImageView` inside my view. On `viewDidLoad` I am animating (moving up) button and image and setting them on some specific position. But when user taps on a textfield to edit it, as the keyboard appears the button and image move back to their original positions.

I don't want any view to move back after my animation finishes. The keyboard appearance is messing up my views. Why its happening or how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: How did you manage to solve the issue ? Thanks